# An asymptotic behavior regarding bivariate normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is bivariate Normal with $E(Z_1)=E(Z_2)=0$, $Var(Z_1)=Var(Z_2)=1$ and $E(Z_1Z_2)= \rho\in (0,1)$.

I am interested in the large $z$ behavior of the following  :
$$
\frac{P(Z_1>z,Z_2<z)}{P(Z_1>z)}.
$$
In particular, I wonder if it is possible to evaluate or bound  sharply
$$
\limsup_{z\rightarrow \infty}\frac{P(Z_1>z,Z_2<z)}{P(Z_1>z)}
$$
in terms of $\rho$.

Comment: You can show that
$$\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac
 {\mathbb P(Z_1 > z \land Z_2 > z)} {\mathbb P(Z_1 > z)} =
-\lim_{z \to \infty} \frac
 {\frac d {dz} \int_z^\infty \! \int_z^\infty
  f_{Z_1, Z_2}(z_1, z_2) \, dz_1 dz_2}
 {f_{Z_1}(z)} = \\
2 \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac
 {\int_z^\infty f_{Z_1, Z_2}(z, z_2) \, dz_2}
 {f_{Z_1}(z)} =
2 \lim_{z \to \infty} \mathbb P {\left(
 Z_2 > z \sqrt \frac {1 - \rho} {1 + \rho} \right)}.$$